# Property Secured Set

Tags: c#, .net, properties, private-members

I am just drawing a blank here.   Have a class that I want read only properties on the class but an admin type function that can update a property.

```
public class Group : Object, INotifyPropertyChanged
{   // this is read only admin is via UserGroupAdmin
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    } 

    public Int16 ID { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public override bool Equals(Object obj)
        {
            //Check for null and compare run-time types.
            if (obj == null || !(obj is Group)) return false;
            Group item = (Group)obj;
            return (ID == item.ID);
        }

    public override int GetHashCode() { return (int)ID; }
    public Group(Int16 id, string name)
    { ID = id; Name = name;  }
 }
```

What I would like is an admin type function

```
public group ReviseGroupName (Group group, string revisedName)
{
   // write revised name to SQL
   // revise group.name
   // return revised group
}
```

The SQL part I know.  What I considered was just creating a new group with the same ID and hashcode and returning it.

Comment: You want to be able to set the `Name` property in the `ReviseGroupName` function event though it is private? To which class does `ReviseGroupName` belong to and how does it relate to `Group`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `Admin` is a nested class in `Group` you can set the private property in the function:

```
public class Group
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public class Admin
    {
        public Group ReviseGroupName (Group group, string revisedName)
        {
            group.Name = revisedName;
            return group;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not really what I was looking for but on reflection it was not a well thought out question.